# Can we set server-side session by making http call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, webforms

I am migrating old ASP.NET WEB Form project to Angular app with ASP.NET web API. 
The requirement is to merge the newly designed angular module (say login section) with old asp.net application. The new application should be functional and work together with the old ASP.NET web form project.

Now the problem I am facing is, when I log in and try to navigate to other .aspx pages, they need some session values (which old login page used to set) to work without breaking the application.

I tried to achieve this by making HTTP call to a dummy .aspx page. I passed all the session values as query parameters and set in on the server side. It's working fine.

Is it a right approach for achieving this or is there any better way? Will there be any complication later as the application grows?

Comment: If any of these values contain sensitive data, I would put them into an HTTP-ONLY cookie instead.

Comment: Good point, but data is not that sensitive in my case.